# Middleware gets hit way too many times while next.js is compiling

Tags: express, middleware, next.js

Iam using next.js and express.js . if I use a middleware (server.use(req, res, next)) it gets hit dozen times while the page is compiling, which makes my app crash completly ...

```
const express = require('express')
const next = require('next')

const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const app = next({ dev })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

console.log('page loaded')

app.prepare().then(() => {
const server = express()

server.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log('ping')
  next();
})

server.get('/', (req, res) => {
  return app.render(req, res, '/index', req.query)
})

server.get('*', (req, res) => {
  return handle(req, res)
})

server.listen(port, err => {
  if (err) throw err
  console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`)
})
})
```

If I try to load the page, it prints

```
ping
ping
ping
ping
ping
ping
ping
ping
ping
ping
ping
ping
ping
ping
ping
```

of course if I put a real middleware here it makes everything crash ...

I wish for the middleware to run only if the page is actually requesting something ... So only once per 'real user' request

Comment: the page returns ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: I found a way to avoid it, I never use app.use, instead I use middlewares as callback functions as they are chained ! Result is amazing, they only load once.         example :      app.get('/index', middleware_here, (req,res) => {} )

Comment: Turns out this is all bad practice, they are not supposed to work together this way but backend and front should be seperated and run on different ports.

Comment: Why is it bad practice? Also do you have a link to any code? (I appreciate the bit you put there), I'm just curious what the rest would look like. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I had the similar trouble, but only on client-side. In my case there were a lot of parasitic requests (trackers, internal API, fonts, some `_next_static` things). They triggered the middleware and it was the reason of `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`.

So, as for me, filtering parasitic requests and redirects helped to solve the problem:

```
if (new RegExp(/^.*(fonts|_next|vk.com|favicon).*$/).test(request.url)) {
  return NextResponse.next()
}
```